# Can I access changed parameters in an after/around plugin?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, after-plugin

I want to access a parameter of a method in an *after* plugin. The value of the parameter has been changed inside the original method, and I want to access the modified value. Example:

```
class vendorClass
{
    function paintBlue($room, $options)
    {
        // ...
        $options['color'] = 'light green';
    }
}
```

Now, my plugin looks like this:

```
class myPerfectMagentoPlugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function afterPaintBlue($subject, $result, $room, $options)
    {
          // This $options array does not contain the color value:
          var_dump($options);
    }
}
```

How can I access the modified content of the `$options` variable in an *after* plugin?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to access that value in either an after or around plugin.

Answer (score 2):

@shawn-abramson,  right but if you do some changes at the original method then you can access the parameters of the change at **around, after plugin.**

If you pass this `two-parameters ($room, $options)` with a return of original function then you can data of both **$room, $options**   at around and after plugin.

### Original Method:

```
class vendorClass
{
    function paintBlue($room, $options)
    {
        // ...
        $options['color'] = 'light green'; 

        // Passing in array variable
        return [
            'room' => $room,
            'options'   => $options)
        ];
    }
}
```

### After Plugin method:

```
class myPerfectMagentoPlugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function afterPaintBlue($subject, $result, $room, $options)
    {
          $modifiedRoom =$result['room'];
          $modifiedOptions =$result['options'];
    }
}
```

### Around Plugin Method

```
class myPerfectMagentoPlugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function aroundPaintBlue($subject, \Callable $proceed, $room, $options)
    {
        // run original Method
        $result = $proceed($room, $options);    

        $modifiedRoom =$result['room'];
        $modifiedOptions =$result['options'];
    }
}
```

Comment: true - but if the original method is in the vendor folder, we might need a patch for this...